# load images dynamically in php from mysql database into a jquery slider

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a web application that involves having users upload pictures to the site. On the homepage, I dynamically show the newest pictures/items uploaded in PHP, limiting it to ten. However, the page looks so static and I have searched on Google, bing, ask, yahoo, etc for days now and haven't had any answers.

I have written the code to store store the images, and get them from the db.
The images are shown on the homepage, and the only thing i have left to do is load it in a slider.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY item_date_added DESC LIMIT 10")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //$user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $item_name = $row['item_name'];
    $item_id = $row['item_id'];

    $check_pic = "users/$item_name.jpg";

    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
        $show_pic = "<img src=\"users/$item_name.jpg\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\" border=\"5\" id='img'/>";

        //$user_pic3 = "<img src=\"users/$rid/image01.jpg\" width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" border=\"1\" />";
        //$MemberDisplayList .= '<a href="profile2/index.php?id=' . $rid . '">' . $user_pic3 . '</a>';
        $i++;
        $show_new_items .= "<a href='item_view?item_id=$item_id&&session_item=$item_id'>$show_pic</a>";
    }
    $newly_listed_names .= " <a href='item_view?item_id=$item_id&&session_item=$item_id'> $item_name </a> | ";
}
```

///////// END  SHOW NEWLY ADDED ITEMS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

the newly added items in echoed in a div in the body.

Can anyone help me please! it's been bothering me for a while now. Thanks.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://knowanevent.in). On homepage it is retrieving images dynamically and loading to slider.

Comment: I have written the code to store store the images, and get them from the db.
The images are shown on the homepage, and the only thing i have left to do is load it in a slider. The jquery plugin is not set yet. That's where i got the problem.

Comment: ok, give me a minute to post the code.

Comment: You can use jquery plugins such as [Nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). Or you can follow this [link](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/03/20-professional-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/).

Comment: i tried nivo but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You can try different jquery plugin and integrate it with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Nivo, you need to generate html that looks something like this... ([Download the nivo demo](http://dev7studios.com/downloads/49) and open up the `demo.html` for the full source).

So all you need to do is output your images in a loop inside the `slider` div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $item_name = $row['item_name'];
            $item_id = $row['item_id'];
            $check_pic = "users/$item_name.jpg";
            if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
                print "<img src=\"users/$item_name.jpg\"/>";
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
            <img src="images/2.jpg" data-thumb="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but the images are to be loaded from the db. like a foreach statement, displaying them. After getting it from the db in my script above, i should go like : foreach($a as $show_new_items){ $c = $a } which would contain the img src, this however isn't working properly, any suggestions?

Comment: You're _not_ storing images in the db - at least from your snippet. You're storing the path to the images in your db. I've edited with an example

Comment: ya, sorry, im storing the images in a folder. Thanks a lot, i would implement it and let you know the outcome, thanks! :)

Comment: its work but image size is to big how can i managed them which .css file i change?

Comment: @pratik You can use CSS to resize the images - just add a class to the `print "<img src=""....` line - but this means the client is downloading a big image and then resizing it. A better approach would be to either resize the images beforehand or using a thumbnail script to do the resize on-the-fly. Why make the user download a big image when they won't see it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugins such as [Nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). Or you can try different jquery plugin from this [link](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/03/20-professional-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/). And integrate it with your code.

Comment: i do not know how to implement them, any help?

Comment: @rasheeda Check this [one](http://rtur.net/blog/post/2011/09/09/Tutorial-Building-NivoSlider-Extension-(Part-1).aspx). Also [this](http://serifaddons.com/nivo-slider-webplus.html).